# Qt project set to version 5 but qtcreator still looking for qt4 header files?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is a screenshot from the project view:

[image]

Here is the .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-05-18T15:34:14
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = bedcoll
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
QMAKE_CC = clang
QMAKE_CXX = clang++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/c++/4.8
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost
LIBS += -lboost_system
LIBS += -lboost_filesystem
LIBS += -lboost_program_options

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += \
    src/util.cpp \
    src/bedcoll.cpp \
    src/main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    src/collgen_memo.h \
    src/util.h \
    src/bedcoll.h \
    src/error_enum.h
```

This project builds without any problem in a kubuntu 13.10, but after upgrading to 14.04, it gives the following error:

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:1045: error: undefined reference to `QString::toAscii() const'
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:880: error: undefined reference to `QString::free(QString::Data*)'
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:879: error: undefined reference to `QString::shared_null'
```

Kubuntu 14.04 ships qt5 as default, but qtcreator is still looking for qt4, very confusing.

Comment: Try to clean the project build and make files. Clean .user file and open the project with Qt 5 kit.

Comment: The place you should check first is in the Options dialog. Check Qt versions, compilers (probably just 1 in Linux), and Kits which combine these. Once you have Qt5 Kit, add it to the project, to get a build which uses the Kit.

Answer (score 1):

@Netjat is right, cleaning up solves the problem, in fact there is a shortcut, just right click on the project and choose "rebuild".